# Angular 2 - dynamically name variables

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I have the following code, which is an array with days...

```
working_days = [
  'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'
];
```

I want to append the day to `#child`, something like `#child+'_'+work_day`. Is this possible? Because I want to add each as a child view, in my component, so I can access it and set some data on view load like:

```
@ViewChild('child_monday') monday_picker
```

Here's my code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let work_day of working_days;let i = index">

  <ion-label>
    {{work_day}} 
    <ion-icon name="clock" style="position:absolute;right:20px;z-index:99999999;opacity:1"></ion-icon>
  </ion-label>

  <ion-checkbox #checkbox disabled></ion-checkbox>

  <ion-multi-picker #child item-content 
    [multiPickerColumns]="simpleColumns" 
    (ionChange)="hoursSelect(work_day,child,checkbox);" 
    class="custom-multi-picker">
  </ion-multi-picker>

</ion-item>
```

Comment: no, that's not possible, why cant use use `@ViewChildren('child')`?

Comment: Because it creates 7 elements how do I know for example how to point to the element for Tuesday let's say in my code?

Comment: You can create directive and pass `workDay` as `@Input` And Then use `@ViewChildren(YourDirective)`

Comment: @yurzui is right as always)

Comment: What version of angular are you using?